# Как можно разбить JSON файл чтобы выводил данные в виде ключ - значение?

Tags: python, json

Как можно разбить JSON файл чтобы выводил данные в виде ключ - значение? JSON файл bank.json:

```
{
  "name": "BankingBotRus",
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "other",
      "examples": [
        {
          "text": "Как подключить эту услугу?"
        },
        {
          "text": "Вы дату пишите года?"
        },
        {
          "text": "оплачивать коммунальные услуги через другой банк"
        },
        {
          "text": "Сколько ещё ждать по моему вопросу ?"
        },
        {
          "text": "Мне нужны мои деньги"
        }
      ],
      "description": "Риторические вопросы"
    },
    {
      "intent": "credit",
      "examples": [
        {
          "text": "скажите, кредит закрылся?"
        },
        {
          "text": "Можно ли оплачивать кредит зачисляя деньги на карту с другой карты стороннего банка?"
        },
        {
          "text": "Сообщите мне минимальный платёж ,который я должна на карту внести с учётом смс и тп"
        },
        {
          "text": "Пришла смс о просроченной задолженности по кредиту.мне сказали спишут с карты"
        }
      ],
      "description": "Вопрос по погашению кредита"
    },
    {
      "intent": "bonus",
      "examples": [
        {
          "text": "бонусы  сразу начислялись"
        },
        {
          "text": "Добрый вечер. Нет хотел узнать до какого числа начисляются бонусы. Спасибо"
        },
        {
          "text": "Добрый день?Подскажите пожалуйста как мне узнать бонусы как начисляются."
        },
        {
          "text": "бонусы будут начисляться"
        },
        {
          "text": "сколько у меня бонусов"
        },
        {
          "text": "А как зарегистрировать баллы на этой карте?"
        },
        {
          "text": "Здравствуйте А как начисляться бонус?"
        }
      ],
      "description": "Начисление бонусов"
    },
    {
      "intent": "sms",
      "examples": [
        {
          "text": "отключит смс информации?"
        },
        {
          "text": "отключить смс рассылку?"
        },
        {
          "text": "хочу выключить смс уведомления"
        },
        {
          "text": "Как отключить смс инфо с карты"
        },
        {
          "text": "Прошу отключить смс инфо"
        },
        {
          "text": "Как отключить sms уведомления?"
        },
        {
          "text": "надоели смс"
        },
        {
          "text": "убрать смски"
        },
        {
          "text": "Необходимо отключить смс уведомление"
        },
        {
          "text": "Как отключить смс уведомление?"
        },
        {
          "text": "Отключила!.Смс возобновятся?"
        }
      ],
      "description": "Отключить смс-информирование"
    }
  ]
}
```

Код:

```
# Python program to read
# json file


import json

# Opening JSON file
f = open('bank.json',)

# returns JSON object as
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)

# Iterating through the json
# list
for i in data['intents']:
    print(i)

# Closing file
f.close()
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример ожидаемого результата

Comment: Ок, это несложно. На каком шаге вы остановились? Считывание из файла json и получение объекта питона уже сделали?

Comment: Был где-то тут уже подобный вопрос, и не один раз

Comment: @gil9red да сделала `


import json

# Opening JSON file
f = open('bank.json',)

# returns JSON object as
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)

# Iterating through the json
# list
for i in data['intents']:
 print(i)

# Closing file
f.close()
`

Comment: @CrazyElf видела только на php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы перебираете значения по ключу `intents`, вы получите словари с ключами `intent` и `examples`, а по ключу `examples` находится список из словарей с ключом `text`.

Получается, что будет дополнительный цикл по значениям ключа `examples`

Пример:

```
for intent in data['intents']:
    for example in intent['examples']:
        print(f'\t{example}')
```

Если еще нужно только текст вытаскивать, то:

```
for intent in data['intents']:
    for example in intent['examples']:
        text = example['text']
        print(f'\t{text}')
```

---

**PS.**

Чтобы не было кракозябр, открывайте файл в кодировке `utf-8`:

```
f = open('bank.json', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое вам, если я правильно поняла здесь так же учитывается вывод список словарей их с отступом в символ табуляции да?

Comment: @Alina, блин, про него забыл... Символ табуляции это строка `\t`, добавлю в ответ

Comment: увидела, спасибо вам огромное!)

Comment: @Alina, пожалуйста :)